# Нужно достать из вывода значение Serial Number

Tags: python, windows, ос

Есть код:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    print (item)

print('Серийный номер вашего жесткого диска: ', item)
```

Вывод:

```
Серийный номер вашего жесткого диска:  
instance of Win32_PhysicalMedia
{
        SerialNumber = "     WD-WCC*********";
        Tag = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0";
};
```

Нужно чтобы выводилось только значение SerialNumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно всего лишь сделать:

```
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    print (item.SerialNumber)
```